# what is the IP address of my heroku application

Tags: python, django, heroku

So in my django application, i'm running a task that will request from an api some data in the form of json.

in order for me to get this data, i need to give the IP address of where the requests are going to come from (my heroku app)

how do i get the ip address in which my heroku application will request at

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the URL to app?

Comment: @Casey https://api.heroesofnewerth.com/request_token.php

Answer (score 11):

Heroku does not provide a static IP by itself but you can use addons to achieve this goal. This limitation is discussed here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains

Generally sites use URL instead of IP address to authenticate requests. You can use [zerigo_dns](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/zerigo_dns) to get an static IP address for your Heroku app.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns link for `Zerigo setup`

Comment: I understand that heroku doesn't provide a static IP, but the app must have *some* IP at all times, is there a way (perhaps a heroku command) to obtain it?

Comment: please note this ***This add-on is being shut down and can no longer be provisioned. If your app uses this add-on, you should switch to a different DNS management solution as soon as possible. The PointDNS add-on is a recommended replacement.** use this link [point dns](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/pointdns)

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge you can not get an ip for a heroku application. You could create a proxy with a known ip that serves as a middleman for the application. Otherwise you might want to look at whether heroku is still the correct solution for you

Comment: It's not so bad. You could try this too http://blog.quotaguard.com/get-a-static-ip-on-heroku/