# Can't connect Node.js server to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, tedious

I'm running a simple Node.js server on Heroku. I've set up an Azure SQL database and I'm just trying to establish a connection to it from the server. I'm using [tedious.js](http://pekim.github.io/tedious/) to connect. As far as I can tell, I'm following the patterns in the docs, but the connection doesn't go through. This is the code I have (altered username and password). For now, the connect function is called upon a GET request to the "/data" page from my browser, but the page never loads and the connection never goes through. Any pointers?

```
var azure = require("azure-storage");

var Connection = require("tedious").Connection;

var config = {
  Server : "my-db.database.windows",
  username : "XXXXX",
  password : "XXXXX",
  options : {
    port: 1433,
    Database : "my-db",
    connectTimeout : 3000,
  },
};


var connection = new Connection(config);

function connect(request, response) {
  connection.on("connect", function(error) {
    //If no error, then good to go
    console.log("Connected to database! Booyah.");
    executeStatement();

    response.send("Connected to database! Booyah.");
  }, function (info) {
    console.log(info);
  });
}

exports.connect = connect;
```

Comment: I know you intentionally obscured username and password but... the `Server` uri is missing `.net` at the end. Not sure if your real code is missing it too - that would be an issue. Also: Did you open the SQL Database firewall to allow for incoming connections from your node app?

Comment: The .net was missing in the code - not sure how that happened. I added that. And I've setup a firewall rule for my IP address. Should I be using my machine's IP? Or is there a separate IP I should use from heroku for the server?

Comment: it's whatever IP your traffic is coming from, into SQL Database. I'll post as answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I echo the answers provided by the community. Here is a quick code sample that can help you get started -

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
    userName: 'yourusername',
    password: 'yourpassword',
    server: 'yourserver.database.windows.net',
    // When you connect to Azure SQL Database, you need these next options.
    options: {encrypt: true, database: 'AdventureWorks'}
};
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    // If no error, then good to proceed.
    console.log("Connected");
    executeStatement();
    //executeStatement1();

});

var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;

function executeStatement() {
    request = new Request("SELECT TOP 10 Title, FirstName, LastName from SalesLT.Customer;", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);} 
    });
    var result = "";
    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
          if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
          } else {
            result+= column.value + " ";
          }
        });
        console.log(result);
        result ="";
    });

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}
function executeStatement1() {
    request = new Request("INSERT SalesLT.Product (Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, SellStartDate) OUTPUT INSERTED.ProductID VALUES (@Name, @Number, @Cost, @Price, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);", function(err) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);} 
    });
    request.addParameter('Name', TYPES.NVarChar,'SQL Server Express 2014');
    request.addParameter('Number', TYPES.NVarChar , 'SQLEXPRESS2014');
    request.addParameter('Cost', TYPES.Int, 11);
    request.addParameter('Price', TYPES.Int,11);
    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
          if (column.value === null) {
            console.log('NULL');
          } else {
            console.log("Product id of inserted item is " + column.value);
          }
        });
    });     
    connection.execSql(request);
}
```

About the firewall rule, it depends on where you are running the app. If you are running it on Heroku, you have to add the IP of the Heroku server. Is it a Linux VM? Here is a stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932218/what-is-the-ip-address-of-my-heroku-application) that you might want to check out.

Comment: Ok, I think I've narrowed this down a bit. First, it wasn't catching the username properly because my code had "username", instead of the proper "userName". So I fixed that, and now it recognizes my username when I try to make a connection. But the login still fails...the firewall rule is set. This is the error I get in the console, along with the stack trace:

"message: 'Login failed for user \'cweber105\'.',
code: 'ELOGIN' }"

Comment: are you specifying encrypt = true?

Comment: Yes, should I not be?

Comment: If I don't include encrypt, it has a default value of false, and the body of connection.on() doesn't even execute. If it's true, the body executes, but I get an error about the login failing.

Comment: You definitely should be! It might be a good idea to make sure your username+password combo is correct. Did you try GUI tools like SSMS to make sure its working?

Comment: I haven't tried a GUI. I'll try giving that a shot though. I hope this isn't a dumb mistake, but does the fact that I'm on a Mac matter? I assumed Windows/Mac didn't matter because either way it's Node.js interacting with the db. Is that a bad assumption to make?

Comment: absolutely should matter! especially for something like authentication. Let me know if you have some luck with the GUI. I work at Microsoft and I am happy to setup a call with you to debug this if you still have issues

Comment: I downloaded a GUI called DbVisualizer, and I managed to successfully ping the server. But I still can't connect to the DB. If you'd be willing to chat, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: absolutely! shoot an email to me at meetb@microsoft.com

Comment: I had a chat with @cweber105 offline and we were able to fix the login issue with a password reset. We verified the script above to make sure Tedious and Azure SQL DB connected just fine

Answer (score 0):

First: the connection string needs to be `cultureofthefewpractice.database.windows.net` - you're missing `.net` at the end.

Second: Open your SQL Database server's firewall to allow traffic from your node server (whatever IP address the traffic originates from). SQL Database allows you to specify IP ranges (and multiple ranges).

Comment: All traffic to the database is coming through the node server on heroku. How can I find out which IP to set up the firewall for?

Comment: You'll need to figure out your ip address from heroku - I don't work with heroku, couldn't guide you there. For a test, at least, you can simply open up the full ip range on SQL Database (0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255) just to see if traffic flows through.

Comment: Ok. Well, I added firewall rule for all IP's, but still no go. Any other thoughts? Is there a way I can view a log of what's happening? I'm on a Mac, and the console is printing a few things. Gibberish to me:

5/10/16 2:09:46.863 PM SpotlightNetHelper[675]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 4467 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
5/10/16 2:09:49.917 PM WindowServer[186]: send_datagram_available_ping: pid 547 failed to act on a ping it dequeued before timing out.