# What should be the local host address for the io when deploying it on a cloud server like heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy my chat app on heroku but I can't figure out the port address for the io variable when it is deployed on a server.

```
Let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku sets the PORT environment variable for your app. You can use it like this:

```
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:" + process.env.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url provided for the hoste4d application. Also refer [what is the IP address of my heroku application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932218/what-is-the-ip-address-of-my-heroku-application/31932476).

Answer (score 0):

You no need to define the url. Just use the below code.

```js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

let socket=io()
```

Comment: welcome dude. I forgot to mention that you no need to use the URL because you are using the default namespace. The default namespace does not require any URL.