# Google Cloud postgres – connecting from Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I was using Postgres addon on Heroku and was connecting to the database using `DATABASE_URL` env var.

I now need to switch to Google Cloud Platform Postgres. I've created an instance and successfully added my local connection to the `Authorised networks`. Yet it seems that [Heroku does not provide a static IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932218/what-is-the-ip-address-of-my-heroku-application) for its apps.

My question is then – is it possible to connect my Heroku app to a Postgres database from the Google Cloud Platform? If yes – what's the best way to do it?

Comment: which language is your Heroku app written in?

Comment: It uses NodeJS (JavaScript)

Comment: You will want to run the Cloud SQL Proxy alongside your application. This thread might be useful for your use-case. [Node and Cloud SQL with Heroku](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/48)

Comment: @JackWotherspoon you should post your last comment as an answer.

Comment: @OsvaldoLópez Good call, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to run the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) alongside your application. This will allow your Heroku App to connect to Cloud SQL without the need to worry about changing and adding IPs to your `Authorized Networks`.

This thread might be useful for your use-case. [Node and Cloud SQL with Heroku](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/48)